# What is the optimal way of querying array with a lot of objectIds

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, query-string

I have an array of MongoDB Object IDs which I want to send to my nodejs server in order to get the objects' data.
The problem is that this array contains hundreds of IDs and I am not sure how should I fetch and query it as concatenating it to the query string will not do as the maximal URL can have up to 2048 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following things:

**If records in DB ordered by _id**

- Send an array of Ids in the `POST` request or send Min and max Id only in the query parameter in the `GET` request.
- Instead, query for individual Id(objectId) or doing `{$in : [ObjectId( )... ObjectId.....]}` do as mentioned in below point.
- Using min and max id from an array, query DB like this:

  `User.find({"_id":{$lte: idmax,$gte:idmin}})`

**If records are not ordered on _id:**

```
 User.find({"_id":{$in:[_id1,id_2.....]})
```

> **PS: Learn more about range queries**.
>
> The relationship between the order of ObjectId values and generation
>   time is not strict within a single second. If multiple systems, or
>   multiple processes or threads on a single system generate values,
>   within a single second; ObjectId values do not represent a strict
>   insertion order. Clock skew between clients can also result in
>   non-strict ordering even for values, because client drivers generate
>   ObjectId values, not the mongod process. So if this is a case you will
>   have to query using in operator `{$in : [ObjectId( ). ObjectId.....]}`
>
> **Long story short: If ids are not in the order in DB you will have to use
>   the `in` operator because otherwise, the range query will fetch
>   extra-record.**